# Mostrar e esconder div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou precisando fazer uma função que que quando clicada somente as as div com a classe passada fique visíveis e as demais fique ocultas.

```
<a href="javascript:teste('minhaDiv');" class="expander">Link</a>
<a href="javascript:teste('minhaDivo');" class="expander">Link</a>
<div class="container">
   <div class="minhaDiv" style="display: none">Div que aparece e some</div>
   <div class="minhaDiv" style="display: none">Div que aparece e some</div>
   <div class="minhaDiv" style="display: none">Div que aparece e some</div>
   <div class="minhaDivo" style="display: none">Div que aparece e some</div>
  <div class="minhaDivo" style="display: none">Div que aparece e some</div>
</div>

function teste(div){
    $('.container').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('class') = div){
            $(this).show();     
        }else{
        $(this).hide()
     };
    });
}
```

Comment: Esse seu código não funciona ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que deste jeito va atender suas expectativas, com um código fácil de entender

```js
function teste(div){    
    $(".container > div").hide();
    $('.' + div).show();    
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="teste('minhaDiv');" class="expander">Link1</a>
<a onclick="teste('minhaDivo');" class="expander">Link2</a>
<div class="container">
   <div class="minhaDiv" style="display: none">Div que aparece e some</div>
   <div class="minhaDiv" style="display: none">Div que aparece e some</div>
   <div class="minhaDiv" style="display: none">Div que aparece e some</div>
   <div class="minhaDivo" style="display: none">Div que aparece e some</div>
  <div class="minhaDivo" style="display: none">Div que aparece e some</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não deu certo "TypeError: a is undefined";

Comment: O código acima funciona, vc pode executa-lo deve haver algo a mais no seu código provavelmente uma variavel "a" que não foi definida

Comment: Esse erro que retorna "jquery.js:3531 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined"

Answer (score 4):

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
function teste(div) {
    $('.container > div').each(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).hasClass(div));
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:teste('minhaDiv');" class="expander">Link</a>
<a href="javascript:teste('minhaDivo');" class="expander">Link</a>
<div class="container">
    <div class="minhaDiv" style="display: none">Div que aparece e some</div>
    <div class="minhaDiv" style="display: none">Div que aparece e some</div>
    <div class="minhaDiv" style="display: none">Div que aparece e some</div>
    <div class="minhaDivo" style="display: none">Div que aparece e some</div>
    <div class="minhaDivo" style="display: none">Div que aparece e some</div>
</div>
```

A ideia é:

- `$('.container > div')` seleciona todas as divs dentro de `container`
- `$(this).toggle(...)` mostra ou esconde consoante o argumento passado seja `true` ou `false`
- `$(this).hasClass(div)` verifica se o elemento tem essa classe

Comment: Aqui não deu certo no primeiro click ja escondeu ".container"

Comment: @PauloAmaral o meu exemplo funciona como queres?

Answer (score 3):

Tem, 2 problemas no seu método:

1. o if tem que ser "==", quando usa um único "=", você está agregando valor dentro da condição.
2. você precisa informar o elemento correto que irá fazer o loop

No caso é a div dentro do seu container:

```
 function teste(div){
        $('.container div').each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('class') == div) {
                $(this).show();     
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
   }
```

Comment: `+1`  por explicares o `=`.  Aviso para quem usar: se o elemento tiver mais que uma classe o `$(this).attr('class') == div` vai dar `false`

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma é usar [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) do jQuery:

```
  $('div.'+div).siblings().hide();
  $('div[class="'+ div +'"]').css("display","inline");
```

```js
function teste(div) {
  $('div.'+div).siblings().hide();
  $('div[class="'+ div +'"]').css("display","inline"); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="teste('minhaDiv');" class="expander">Link</a>
<a onclick="teste('minhaDivo');" class="expander">Link</a>
<div class="container">
  <div class="minhaDiv" style="display: none">Div que aparece e some 1</div>
  <div class="minhaDiv" style="display: none">Div que aparece e some 1</div>
  <div class="minhaDiv" style="display: none">Div que aparece e some 1</div>
  <div class="minhaDivo" style="display: none">Div que aparece e some 2</div>
  <div class="minhaDivo" style="display: none">Div que aparece e some 2</div>
</div>
```